# Link xCode library (.a) into MonoTouch

Tags: xcode, xamarin.ios, monodevelop

Is there a simple step-by-step example available which explains how to to link a xCode library (.a) into a Monotouch project? Just a class with a "helloworld()" method would be enough...

Kindly regards,
Wouter Slotegraaf

Answer (score 1):

Try this thread: http://monotouch.2284126.n4.nabble.com/linking-and-using-Objc-a-files-td3537034.html